# Bootstrap re-positioning divs based on visibility of other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to re-position `div` based on the visibility of other `divs`. When the screen size is reduced, they stack up and hiding/showing any div automatically makes the stacked up `divs` to show/hide without any blank area, but not in normal screen size (laptop/desktop).

Take a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yijuhifevole/1)

Now, uncheck any checkbox. If a row has only one div shown, then I want it resized so that it occupies the hidden div too.

I am using a col-md-6 class for the 2x2 divs in the page.

```
<div class="col-md-6 column" id="1col"> </div>
```

Comment: could you just update the class to col-md-12 (or simply remove col-md-6- bc that will do the same thing) - when the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I did that and it comes up well. But there is lot of combinations in the 4 checkboxes. Isn't there a simple way of re sizing a div to occupy the container width if the other div is hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: First, add a class name to your `.row` class so you don't affect it in other places, then you use the following CSS

```
.row{display:flex; justify-content:space-around}
.column{display:inline-flex; height:100%; width:auto;}
```

of course you'll replace `.row` with (say) `.row.myColumns` but in the meanwhile you can use just this code to test in your jsbin. I don't have an account there and don't plan to signup just to test so I couldn't fork it, but I played with your code using 2, 3 and then moving all four columns inside a single row and it works perfectly, so try it by yourself.